# How should I handle tracking fragment page views in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I've been searching through the [Google Analytics documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview), but I still don't understand how I should track page views for a single "page" site that uses ajax to reveal different views. I use [shebang URLs and _escaped_fragment_](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/) to help search engines understand the site layout, but our analytics guy told me to strip out the `#!` part of the URL when tracking, so when you visit `mysite.com/#!/fish/bonker` we would run:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/fish/bonker"]);
```

but that seems wrong to me. Wouldn't we want our tracked URLs to align with what Google actually spiders? Is there anything wrong with tracking `_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "#!/fish/bonker"]);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to recognize that there is a wall between Google Analytics and Google Search. There's no reason you would be penalized by having your URLs in one not correspond to what the other sees.

`escaped_fragment` is purely a semi-standard for crawlers seeking to crawl AJAX content.

By default, Google Analytics does the equivalent when you don't pass a custom pageview value:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", location.pathname+location.search]);
```

If you want to have it also track the `anchor` value, you can simply pass it on your own:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", location.pathname+location.search+location.hash]);
```

The benefit here is that the URLs will correspond with "real" URLs.

Long story short: You're perfectly fine doing your proposed method; I would prefer the latter (explicitly passing the actual `location.hash`, not a hacked version of it), but both work.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I actually do use `location.hash` where the browser understands `window.onhashchange`, but for others I'm actually firing the event when anchors are clicked, so in that case it's actually the value of the `href` attribute (normalized for consistency).